# How to add pubsub attribute along with message from Google Sink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-logging

I have implemented the architecture as per link
https://towardsdatascience.com/bigquery-cloud-functions-how-to-run-your-queries-as-soon-as-a-new-google-analytics-table-is-17fbb62f8aaa

But while sending message from sink to pubsub, I want to add an attribute along with the message.
Is there any feature available in sink to add an attribute in the pubsub through sink.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try [adding custom fields](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#custom-fields) to your logs and then create a sink.

> Custom fields are fields within log entries that you can specify to be
> included in the summary line. These fields are populated, and
> highlighted in blue, whenever they are available in your log entries.

[image]

When you've added a label then create a sink to pub/sub. I don't know if this will work in your use case but it's worh a shot.